# Parse background job migration?

Tags: parse-platform, cron

So with parse shutting down, i'm looking to migrate all the functionality.  One thing I can not think of to easily do is to migrate my parse background jobs.  Has anyone done this already?  If so, what did you use, or what general updates did you have to make?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy to use node-scheduler npm module. You just need to setup the intervals and write your code inside a function, call the function in the scheduler.

Sample code below:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

function doSomething(){
  //write your functionality here
}

var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.second = [5];

var job = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
   doSomething();
});
```